# Why would July (Zerg) build a later second sunken colony in this match against Casy (Terran)?

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

I recently watched the [Casy (Terran) vs July (Zerg) match](https://tl.net/tlpd/korean/games/3159_Casy_vs_July/vod) from [2006-2007 OSL Season 3](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft/2006-2007_Shinhan_Bank_OSL_Season_3). This was game 3 from round 1 of the elimination bracket. The game is notable for being very short and including a deception that tricks July into believing that Terran has expanded when they are actually massing units for an aggressive push.

This deception is accomplished by long distance mining their expansion while the mineral patches are in view of an Overlord (relevant part starts at 5:37):

[image: Deception]

This encourages Zerg to believe that Terran is not pushing off of one base and Zerg therefore plays somewhat less defensively than they would against 1-base aggression.

Approximately 30 seconds later, Casy moves out with his forces. July has Zerglings waiting outside of Casy's base so, they see the leading marines moving out:

[image: Move out]

Upon seeing this move out, July immediately starts a single sunken colony:

[image: Single sunken colony creation]

Approximately 15 seconds later, July starts a second sunken colony:

[image: Second sunken morphing]

The first sunken colony completes almost exactly when the attack hits, but the second is too late to participate in the fight:

[image: Marines and Firebats at July's natural]

It begins morphing as the battle starts and is eliminated right as it finishes:

[image: Second sunken being destroyed]

Why was this second sunken colony created when it was? If July perceived that it was needed, my assumption is that Zerg would have built it at the same time as the first to have it ready on time. Did July realize before the attack that this wasn't a two base play and adjust their response? I didn't see anything obvious in the video to indicate that July picked up any new information as the Terran forces moved across the map that would have revealed the deception.

Comment: This is a very clear question worthy of StackExchange. +1

Answer (score 9):

While we cannot purport to know the exact headspace of a player at any given time, there are two reasonable hypothesis that apply here.

1. Lack of resources - Sunken Colonies cost minerals (and drones!), and a player who is efficiently spending their income may not have much of a bank if, for instance, they realize they have a sudden need for two sunken colonies. At full  saturation, a 15 second delay seems plausible for this, especially if they were also unexpectedly having to make additional combat units.
2. Human Error - Perhaps July initially assessed that they would be able to hold the push with a single sunken colony. Then, second-guessed that initial assessment and decided two would be preferable. Sometimes, even the pros just get things wrong.